# Condicionar en un ciclo for each PHP

Tags: php, html, formularios, bucles, foreach

estoy tratando de ingresar mediante un formulario una serie de arreglos y necesito mostrarlos mediante un ciclo for each, el detalle es que necesito condicionar que si todos los elementos cumplen los requisitos imprima y si uno solo no lo cumple muestre un msj de error. Hasta ahora he logrado casi todo pero al momento de condicionar dentro del for each va mostrando en pantalla y se detiene cuando se ingresa uno que no cumpla pero la idea es que no muestre ninguno hasta que se cumplan todos. Aca el codigo:

Codigo HTML

```
<form action="procesar.php" method="post">
    <label for="Vehiculo1">Datos del vehiculo 1</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="nombre" name="vehiculos[1][marca]"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="placa" name="vehiculos[1][placa]"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="color" name="vehiculos[1][color]"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="peso" name="vehiculos[1][peso]"><br><br>

    <label for="Vehiculo1">Datos del vehiculo 2</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="vehiculos[2][marca]"><br>
    <input type="text" name="vehiculos[2][placa]"><br>
    <input type="text" name="vehiculos[2][color]"><br>
    <input type="text" name="vehiculos[2][peso]"><br><br>

    <label for="Vehiculo1">Datos del vehiculo 3</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="nombre" name="vehiculos[3][marca]"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="placa" name="vehiculos[3][placa]"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="color" name="vehiculos[3][color]"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="peso" name="vehiculos[3][peso]"><br><br>
    <label for="Vehiculo1">Datos del vehiculo 4</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="nombre" name="vehiculos[4][marca]"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="placa" name="vehiculos[4][placa]"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="color" name="vehiculos[4][color]"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="peso" name="vehiculos[4][peso]"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="button">
</form>
```

Codigo PHP

```
if($_POST['vehiculos']){ 

    $vehiculos= $_POST['vehiculos'];
    $numero=1;
    $peso_maximo=800;



    foreach ($vehiculos as $vehiculo) {
        if ($vehiculo['peso']>$peso_maximo) {
             echo "uno de los vehiculos no cumple la condicion";
            break;

        }
        else{
            echo "Carro N#" . $numero . "<br>";
            echo "Marca: " . $vehiculo['marca'] . "<br>";
            echo "Placa: " . $vehiculo['placa'] . "<br>";
            echo "Color: " . $vehiculo['color'] . "<br>";
            echo "Peso: " . $vehiculo['peso'] . "<br><br>";
            $numero++;
        }

}




}
```

Este es el resultado cuando el tercer vehiculo fue el que no cumplio la condicion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un for each lo que hace es analizar todo lo que venga, pero uno por uno. Si el primero cumple lo pinta, si no cumple no lo pinta, si el segundo cumple lo pinta, si no cumple, no lo pinta. Debes de hacer la comprobación de peso fuera. Eso lo haces metiendo todos los pesos en un array y comprobando el array. Una vez compruebes que los pesos no superan 800, pintas, lo puedes ver con un if fuera del foreach.

Comment: pon un foreach que compruebe si algun vehículo tiene errores, y si no hay errores, pones otro foreach que imprima los datos

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if($_POST['vehiculos']){ 

    $vehiculos= $_POST['vehiculos'];
    $numero=1;
    $peso_maximo=800;

    $mensaje = '';



    foreach ($vehiculos as $vehiculo) {
        if ($vehiculo['peso']>$peso_maximo) {
             $mensaje = "uno de los vehiculos no cumple la condicion";
            break;

        }
        else{
            $mensaje .= "Carro N#" . $numero . "<br>";
            $mensaje .= "Marca: " . $vehiculo['marca'] . "<br>";
            $mensaje .= "Placa: " . $vehiculo['placa'] . "<br>";
            $mensaje .= "Color: " . $vehiculo['color'] . "<br>";
            $mensaje .= "Peso: " . $vehiculo['peso'] . "<br><br>";
            $numero++;
        }

}

    echo $mensaje;

}
```

En vez de hacer un `echo` en cada línea, podrías guardar lo que quieres sacar por pantalla en una variable, que mostrarás al final del bucle. Si en algún momento la condición no se cumple, lo que se hará será borrar el contenido del mensaje para meterle la advertencia, en caso de que nunca entre por ahí se va a mostrar el texto con las propiedades de cada vehículo.